# How do you retrieve the costs of a given instance for the past month

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an instance in AWS and would like to determine the cost to run the instance for the past month.

I found the following example...

```
# Step 1: Retrieve Instance IDs
$instances = Get-Ec2Instance
$instanceIds = $instances.Instances.InstanceId

# Step 2: Retrieve Cost Data
$startDate = "2023-01-01"   # Specify your desired start date
$endDate = "2023-08-01"     # Specify your desired end date

$costParams = @{
    TimePeriod = @{
        Start = $startDate
        End = $endDate
    }
    Granularity = "DAILY"
    Filter = @{
        Dimensions = @{
            Key = "SERVICE"
            Values = "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud - Compute"
        }
    }
}


$costData = Get-CECostAndUsage @costParams  -Metric "UsageQuantity" | Where-Object { $_.ResourceId -in $instanceIds }

# Step 3: Parse and Display Cost Data
$costData | ForEach-Object {
    $instanceId = $_.ResourceId
    $cost = $_.Total.UnblendedCost.Amount
    $formattedCost = "{0:C}" -f [double]$cost

    Write-Host "Instance ID: $instanceId | Cost: $formattedCost"
}
```

But it does not work for me. I tried to find other examples on line but could not.